# How to characterize the intersection of images of polynomial functions over number fields

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Let $k$ be a number fields and let $f,g \in k[x]$. Considering $f:k \to k$ and $g: k \to k$ as functions, what statements can we make about the set $f(k) \cap g(k)$? I had some ideas but I'm hoping there is a nice characterization or criterion for the intersection to be finite/infinite.

When $f$ is linear, $f(k) \cap g(k) = g(k)$.

One can also construct examples where there will be no common solutions: take $a \in K$ with $\sqrt{a} \not \in k$, then $f(x) = ax^2$ and $g(x) = x^2$. I expect this to be the generic condition since one can get finiteness using Faltings' theorem / Mordell conjecture. If $p \in f(k) \cap g(k)$ has $x,y \in k$ such that $f(x) - g(y) = 0$, so if $f(x) - g(y)$ has no low degree irreducible factors, the solution set will be finite by the genus degree formula. Ensuring there are no such factors *seems* general, but I'd live some sort of criterion.